# What is wrong with how I'm printing this string list?

Tags: c, for-loop, logical-operators

I created a string list and I used the following code to print it:

```
int i;
char* p = "My\0name\0is\0\0";
for (i = 0; *(p + i) != '\0' && *(p + i + 1) != '\0'; i++)
{
    if (*(p + i) == '\0')
        printf(" ");
    else
        printf("%c", *(p + i));
}
```

Why is this only printing `M`, without the rest of the string?

Comment: Either your string is null (zero) terminated (and then you cannot have null characters inside it) either you know its length somehow.

Comment: If you have never used a debugger before, now is the perfect time to learn it. Using a debugger you can step through the code, line by line, while monitoring variables and their values. Being able to use a debugger is a crucial skill for anyone who wants to do any kind of programming, even as a hobby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a value of `i == 1`, the condition check statement

```
*(p + i) != '\0' && *(p + i + 1) != '\0'
```

fails (*evauates to FALSE*), so the `for` loop terminates.

As per your intentions, you can modify the condition check as

```
for (i = 0; !(*(p + i) == '\0' && *(p + i + 1) == '\0'); i++)
{
    if (*(p + i) == '\0')
        printf(" ");
    else
        printf("%c", *(p + i));
}
```

which, translated to human readable logic, looks like,

*continue until both `*(p + i)` and `*(p + i + 1)` are `'\0'`*

Comment: So I should replace `&&` with `||`

Comment: @UFCInsider -- yes

Answer (score 0):

```
*(p + i + 1)
```

Will equal `\0` when `i` is 1.